# Trigger change event only when two dropdowns elements selected

Tags: jquery

I have a script right now where I'm trying to get certain elements to show only when two specific values from each dropdown is selected. In this case, I only need my elements to show when someone selects Target 1 AND Target 2 OR 3 or 4.

I only need the elements to display once after my targets are selected.

Currently, the problem with my script is I can't figure out the AND/OR logic, nor can I get my elements to only appear once. The 'one' before the change function works fine... is there any alternative to the adds?

```js
$('#target-id').add('#target-id-2').add('#target-id-3').add('#target-id-4').one('change', function() {
  if (this.value !== 'All') {
    $("table thead th.nid").after('<th><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="compare">Compare</button></th>');    
    $('table tbody tr td.compare').append(function(i) {
      return $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        id: 'td' + i,
        class: 'form-check-input',
        value: name
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: we need a fully reproducible example. otherwise it is very difficult to understand what your problem is

Comment: Aside from the issue either add the same class to all the elements and use `$('.target')` to select them, or join the `id` selectors in to a single string: `$('#target-id, #target-id-2, #target-id-N')`. I'd strongly suggest the former, though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To be able to assist, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example